# Как добавить текст "руб." к посчитанному числу с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("div.linked-form__field__label > span:contains(Аванс)").parent("div.linked-form__field__label").next(".linked-form__field__value").find("input").change(function () {
    var field_one = $("div.linked-form__field__label > span:contains(Аванс)").parent("div.linked-form__field__label").next(".linked-form__field__value").find("input").val();

    var budjet = $("label.card-cf-name-label__label > span:contains(Бюджет)").parent("label.card-cf-name-label__label").parent(".linked-form__field__label").next().find("input")[1].value;
    var rest = budjet - field_one;
    $("div.linked-form__field__label > span:contains(Остаток)").parent("div.linked-form__field__label").next(".linked-form__field__value").find("input").val(rest);
    var percent = rest * 100 / budjet;
    $("div.linked-form__field__label > span:contains(Процент)").parent("div.linked-form__field__label").next(".linked-form__field__value").find("input").val(percent);


})
```

Comment: добавьте html код

Answer (score -1):

Переменная + '.руб'.

В JS строки складываются как числа.

Comment: А что вы в html вывести, $('class').html(то что нужно записать);
Что бы добавить к уже существующему значению,, $('class').append('руб.');

Comment: Не торопитесь давать ответ. Поправил опечатки -- система автоматом поставила вам минус за плохой ответ.